# CSS Flexbox Issue in Firefox / IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to get the form to sit horizontally across the bottom of the hero image on a site I'm creating (http://www.mydiligent.com/) and it renders fine in Chrome using flexbox on the  element but for some reason it's not applying the Display: Flex in Firefox or IE. I have the proper vendor prefixes in place as well:

```
#homeForm tbody {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try -moz-box-flex? and what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Is it related to changes in flexbox model? IE10 is based on 22-Mar-2012 version according to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx). More details about these changes here: http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: -moz-box-flex didn't work. Using the most current version of both browsers (IE 11 & FF 29), prefixes based on:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Turns out that for FF & IE I had to select the <tr> class to have the Display: Flex property, where in Chrome it's the <tbody> element that has the Flexbox. Not sure why it would be rendering parent containers differently, but I'll take it. Thanks all.